# Изменение GET параметров на POST в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, url, uri

При переходе между страницами на URL показывает GET параметры

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.(php|html|htm)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\z
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rocketfir,.com/? [R=301,L]
```

После ввода этого кода в .htaccess в URL вместо rocketfirm.com/business.html стал показывать rocketfirm.com/php?login=&name=business, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Исправлять надо не "это". А просто решать исходную задачу по-человечески.

Comment: я в index.php прописал все в POST, оно открывалось POSTом, теперь добавил код в .htaccess, чтобы убрать index.php из URL, и оно показывает GETом

Comment: чтобы убрать index.php из URL не нужно ничего добавлять в  .htaccess. и уж тем более вот этот вот ужас.

Answer (score 0):

После добавления этого кода в .htaccess, все сработало

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```